# Migrating to a sub-folder in VSO with OpsHub

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

In the TFS to VSO migration tool, is it possible to push all changesets from TFS into a sub-folder on VSO?  So $/Proj would now be $/Proj/Archive?  I want to start a new baseline, but have an archive (with history maintained) on VSO.

Also, can a folder be skipped from the check-in process during the migration (like BuildProcessTemplates)?

I don't see any options for either, but I was hoping there's a config file or something where I can set the migration destination root folder to $/Proj/Archive or cloak folders

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do this with the OpsHub tool. It will only let you migrate like for like.

If you want to migrate in this way then you would ned to switch to another tool. The TFS Integration Tools allow you to do these sorts of mappings as part of a migration.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe

Comment: Thank you!  I'm going to check out TFS Int Tools and if that works out, I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. With our free migration utility, it is not possible.

However, this can be achieved through our paid product OpsHub Integration Manager (http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim)

Comment: Luckily the TFS Integration Tools are free :)